# Update a UIView when UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I have an application that has a `UITableView` and a custom `UIView` on the same storyboard. The `UIView` loads a custom chart based upon the selection, and is loading a `UIWebView` with HighChart (the data and html is all locally stored, not being pulled over the network).

When I select the `UITableViewCell`, the view never displays. It loads the subviews (I'm `NSLog`ing that out to console) and all the data is correct, but the display itself never refreshes. I've tried sticking `[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay]` at 20+ different places, but I'm starting to feel like it's something else.

Is it possible that there is an issue because I'm loading a web view? Is it essentially redrawing my `UIView` before the asynchronous call to my `UIWebView` is ready to do anything? What's the easiest way to test this?

Updated with some code (Skipping some, I'll fill in more as requested):

```
@implemention MainViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ***normal viewDidLoad stuff***

    _myCustomView = [[MyCustomViewClass alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,_tableview.frame.origin.y + _tableview.frame.size.height,_tableview.frame.size.width, 176)];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomJsonDataObject *dataObject = [self.jsonDataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [_myCustomView redrawWithDataObject:dataObject];

}

@end

@implementation myCustomViewClass {
   UIScrollView *scrollView 
}

-(void)redrawWithDataObject:(MyCustomJsonDataObject *)dataObj {

   scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:etc];

   // THere are 3 screens initialized: 1 chart data with a UIWebView, and two custom UIViews. 

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.size.width * 3, 176)

   ** initialize web view from custom class **
   [scrollView addSubview:webView];

   ** initialize custom view from custom class **
   [scrollView addSubview:UIView1];

   ** initialize custom view from custom class **
   [scrollView addSubview:UIView2];

   ** set some scrollView properties (scrollable, paging, etc) **

   [self addSubview:scrollView];
   [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

The custom `UIWebView` class takes data from the `JSON` object, and replaces javascript placeholder variables in a local html file, then feeds the new file back into the webView. The others two views are just a bunch of simple labels that populate data from the custom data object.

Comment: Where is your code ? how is it even remotely possible to answer this question with seeing your code. Could be a thousand different things

Comment: I'm trying to come up with some relevant code for you, but there are a couple of issues: 1) It's an enterprise application, which means the code is considered proprietary. 2) The applications is ENORMOUS, and splitting out relevant code chunks can be difficult. I'm trying to put together a fake duplicate of the code isolated from the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue:

_myCustomView was already being defined in the storyboard, so it was initializing itself. When I called the init method in my viewDidLoad, it appears I was adding a SECOND instance of the view, overwriting the first, which is why it displayed blank and didn't appear to refresh. When I removed the init method for the view in viewDidLoad, it worked without issue.